# Why does my Python program issue a runtime error- NZEC( Non-zero exit code)?

Tags: python, runtime-error

This is a CodeChef problem for the November challenge. I donot intend to cheat. My program works well for the test input provided. But the server generates a runtime NZEC error.
Can you help me identify my mistake?

```
T= raw_input()
for i in xrange(int(T)):
    G= raw_input()
    for j in xrange(int(G)):
        I, N, Q = raw_input().split()
        I= int(I)
        N= int(N)
        Q= int(Q)
        a= [I]*N
        print a
        count=0
        for k in xrange(N):
            if((N-k) % 2 != 0):
                if a[k]==1:
                    a[k]=2
                else: a[k]=1
        print a
        for k in xrange(N):
            if( a[k] == Q):
                count= count+1
        print count
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: doesn't `G=raw_input();` should be tabbed (moved few spaces ahead), and what is the `;` that appears in the end of this command?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was properly indented, somehow it didn't copy correctly. I'm more used to C++, hence the semicolon, removed now. It didn't raise an error out of that surprisingly.

Comment: A semicolon is legal in python. And can be used to write multiple statements in a single line.

Comment: The code seems to work properly, you need to check your input parameters which may crash the program,

Comment: Will large input parameters cause this error? I wrote the same program for C++ and I got a runtime error SIGABRT. Are they two the same? And how do I handle large data, in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The problem description](http://www.codechef.com/NOV12/problems/CONFLIP) says that N can be `10**9`. So `a= [I]*N` might require several gigabytes of memory. Your program probably terminates with MemoryError exception that leads to non-zero exit status (`1`).

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks. I'll have to think a way around this.