# Why does my code throws a NON ZERO EXIT CODE runtime error while using Ruby language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runtime-error

[image]

I am trying to solve a HackerEarth problem using Ruby

The problem is provided in the following link:

https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/find-product/

My solution for the problem is here :

```
n = gets.chomp.to_i
a = Array.new
if n <= 1000
  n.times do 
    a << gets.chomp.to_i
  end
end
a.each { |m| print m.to_s + " " }
print "\n"
answer = 1
a.each do |m|
  answer = ( answer * m ) % ( (10**9) + 7)
end
puts "#{answer}"
```

The code throws a Runtime Non zero exit code (NZEC).I am not able to understand the concept of NZEC and what particulary wrong I am doing in this code. Can someone pls help me to understand NZEC and find a work around for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my Python program issue a runtime error- NZEC( Non-zero exit code)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216600/why-does-my-python-program-issue-a-runtime-error-nzec-non-zero-exit-code)

Comment: Please post the actually error message with the trace.

Comment: When I run the code on my desktop, it yields the expected output. However when I run the code in the above link which contains the problems statement , it simply states as   RESULT: Runtime Error - NZEC @thesecretmaster

Comment: Look at the proposed duplicate, it looks like what you want.

Comment: @lorefnon I am sorry I am not able to figure out the solution. Correct me if  I am wrong, but what I can make from the link you provided is one of the variables should be allocated large enough memory to hold the calculation. But how should I do that, since memory allocation happens automatically in Ruby. I am a novice programmer and do not have much knowledge of either python or ruby.Pls help by being elaborate.

Comment: @MaheshMesta Please try running your code locally with large datasets. Refer to the constraints section in the problem statement and run it against a dataset that is close to the upper bounds of that constraint.

Comment: The first step in diagnosing this should be putting the whole thing in a `begin … rescue … end` block to rescue any exception and print out its message and backtrace. (This might not have a different result, but either way it will help narrow down the problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NZEC error appears because, you read the problem a bit quickly.
The first line must contain a single integer `n`, and the second line must contain each element separated by a space.

When I launch your script, it seems I need to press enter between each entry of the array. so when you test your code in hackerhearth I presume that execution failed because it receives no response after the second entry.

There is also a similar problem with your output, you print the full array before display the answer. The problem definition specifies you have to only display the answer.

One possible solution could be the following:

```
n = gets.chomp.to_i
a = gets.chomp.split.map(&:to_i)
answer = 1
a.each do |m|
  answer = ( answer * m ) % ( (10**9) + 7)
end
puts "#{answer}"
```

Comment: @ Yann VERY Thank you very much for precisely explaining to me  what mistakes I have made. Your solution has helped.I should analyze my problem statements more carefully.I am a very novice ruby programmer yet.But,thanks a lot.